# ReactiveSecurityContextHolder in test isn't working as expected

Tags: java, mockito, spring-webflux

I have a simple method which uses the current user's name in a small bit of logic. The code works as expected in use, but I can't seem to get a test to work.

The method I want to test:

```
Mono<Circle> getCircleByIdWithUserPermission(final String circleId) {

    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .flatMap(authentication ->
                    circleRepository.findById(circleId)
                            .flatMap(circle -> circle.getUsers().contains(authentication.getName())
                                    ? Mono.just(circle) : Mono.error(new ForbiddenException()))
            );

}
```

And the test I've written so far:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "test-user")
public void getCircleByIdWithUserPermission() {
    when(circleRepositoryMock.findById("1")).thenReturn(Mono.just(circleOne));

    StepVerifier.create(circleServiceMock.getCircleByIdWithUserPermission("1"))
            .expectNext(circleOne)
            .expectComplete()
            .verify();
}
```

But the test is always failing with `actual: onComplete())` so it never makes use of the `circleRepositoryMock.findById("1")`.

If I remove

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
```

And hard code the test values, it works as expected.

Is there something I'm overlooking here?

Edit:

Mocking is just a simple:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CircleServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CircleServiceImpl circleServiceMock;

    @Mock
    private CircleRepository circleRepositoryMock;

    //..
```

Comment: how do you create  and inject circleRepositoryMock ?

Comment: Hi @MaciejKowalski, I've updated the question with where I'm creating those mocks, is that what were asking?

Comment: What is `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)` actually returning in your test? You say its working if your hardcode values instead, that leads me to believe that the mock is not the problem. Also `@WithMockUser` is a `Spring` annotation that has nothing to do with `Mockito`, so its probably not doing anything during the test.

Comment: as @second wrote, if this is a unit test `@WithMockUser` wont work it needs to be a spring application test.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, you're both correct. Is anyone able to provide an example of how I could test this method?

Comment: I could give you an example on how write a unit test for this using `PowerMockito` to mock away the static method. If you instead need a integration test using spring, I would need to rely on a tutorial (like [`this`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/test-method.html)) myself.

Comment: you can find examples in the official documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server

Comment: Thanks, yes that is what I first looked at. The issue was me trying to mix Mockito annotations with Spring annotations and expecting it to just work.